# Undo history broken in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, undo

Is Eclipse's **undo history broken**? I have been using 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, and now 3.4 versions for the last few years and was always able to undo only about 20-25 changes back in history.

This nonsense has cost me some lost modifications countless times when trying to revert some recent changes (if you reply with "you should commit to svn every 25 changes", I'm going to unleash dragons on you).

There's a setting in **Preferences->Editors->Text Editors->Undo history size** and I set it to 1000 but it didn't help anything.

I'm mostly using **Eclipse** with the **Perl E.P.I.C.** in the **Perl Perspective**, if it matters.

So guys, what's the problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried submitting a bug report? https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/

Comment: No, I haven't - I figured I was editing the wrong setting or doing something else wrong - it's such an obvious feature that it's almost insane to imagine it being broken for years.

Comment: Nothing about Eclipse surprises me anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm experienceing the same problems and I am also using Eclipse with EPIC.

It seems this is a known issue with EPIC, see http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1728227&group_id=75859&atid=545274

Reported in 2007, so I'm surprised it hasn't been fixed :(

**Edit: Yay! This is now fixed in EPIC version 0.6.37**

Comment: Added a comment to that ticket.

Answer (score 1):

Testing show that for low values of the property it does indeed work - I'm using the Java Editor.

Perhaps you can try and see if the Java Editor respects those settings - I'm too lazy to make > 50 changes and undo, and if it does file a bug against E.P.I.C.?

Answer (score -1):

Not a direct answer, but Eclipse maintains a local history of edited files (Context menu -> Restore from local history). Maybe that would be a better way than going back 25 steps in the undo-history.